# GWT asyncdataprovider

Tags: java, gwt

Вопрос в следующем. Есть `CellList`, он берет данные с сервера. Как сделать, чтоб при переходе на предыдущую страницу, по клавише key up select, был на последней записи?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Вы не можете вызвать [.setSelected()](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets.html#selection) или найти последний на текущей странице элемент?

Comment: Вот стандартный пример использования провайдера http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/AsyncDataProvider.html  находясь на второй странице и нажимая клавишу вверх мы переходим на первую, но хотелось бы переходить не на первый элмент, а последний